# Python: Inspecting a standard library

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to inspect the standard library via the interpreter.

```
import inspect

inspect.getsource(list.extend)
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got method_descriptor
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d7b2c0909b78800d1376fd696f73824ea680463/Objects/listobject.c#L873